# angular 5 migration jquery not working

Tags: jquery, angular, migration, angular-cli, angular5

I get some problem with my ANGULAR 5 application.

I use some component that need JQUERY it was functional before the migration I didn t change anything.

I add in my component
declare var jQuery: any;

In package. json

```
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "jstree": "^3.3.4",
```

dev

```
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
```

angular cli

```
      "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "../node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.js",
      "../node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js",
      "../vendor/pace/pace.min.js",
      "../node_modules/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js",
      "../node_modules/simplebar/dist/simplebar.js"
  ],
```

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I'm having the same issue. Compiling my Angular app, I get Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in…

Comment: I found that JQUERY bug if you have an error at the first compilation.

- If I start my compilation without error jQuery is included and working
- If my compilation have an error at the first compilation its like its not included

Answer (score 0):

I tried following and is working fine for me

1. `npm i --save jquery` [Install the `jquery v1.12.4` and add as dependency in `package.json`]
2. go to `.angular-cli.json` and in `scripts[]` add as follows.I am using bootstrap so that is also added

   `scripts: ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"]`
3. Add following to modules where you wish to write the jquery functions

   `import * as $  from 'jquery';`

Hope this resolves your issue. Please make sure you have respective files at mentioned locations.

Answer (score 0):

I found that JQUERY bug if you have an error at the first compilation. 
- If I start my compilation without error jQuery is included and working 
- If my compilation have an error at the first compilation its like its not included

So make your first build working and then there is no problem